# install dependencies doesn't work install and check buttons

Tags: android, adt

[image]

I download ADT, but when I try to create new project I have this window,instal and check button doesn't work. I installed Android support library in SDK Manager. But it does not work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: whether you installed android-build?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: go to Window->Preferences and select Android.
You should see the path for the SDK location. Check if it's pointing at the right version and not at the previous one.

If it's pointing at the previous version, write the new path then Apply and then run SDK manager again and reinstall the missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

According to this bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149, it is a bug